# Pass external URL into ajax javascript

Tags: php, jquery, html, xml, url

I am trying to fetch the contents of an external XML URL, into the javascript's ajax script, but it simply won't accept it, due to CROSS domain issue. I have searched through google regarding this issue, but nothing good so far, everything I've read so far stated that I need to incorporate PHP as well, but with that, the page would take reload.

I simply want that when a user enters a number that number gets passed as an argument in the URL, then displays the XML content in the screen without reloading.

SO any help will be highly appreciated.

Here's my code so far.

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
       $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://lx2.loc.gov:210/lcdb?operation=searchRetrieve&recordSchema=marcxml&version=1.1&maximumRecords=1&query=bath.isbn%3D9781452110103",



            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('record').each(function(){
                var sTitle = $(this).find('datafield[tag="245"]').find('subfield[code="a"]').text();
                 var sAuthor = $(this).find('datafield[tag="100"]').find('subfield[code="a"]').text();
                  var sIsbn = $(this).find('datafield[tag="020"]').find('subfield[code="a"]').text();





                

                  
        
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });


                $("<li></li>").html(sTitle).appendTo("#dvContent ul");
                $("<li></li>").html(sAuthor).appendTo("#dvContent ul");
                $("<li></li>").html(sIsbn).appendTo("#dvContent ul");
                    });
            },
            error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try jsonp ?

Comment: isnt jsonp for JSON data .. I am expecting an XML data

Comment: then why did you use `getJSON`

Comment: that is a different URL , it's just helping me get the cover image ,plz ignore that

Comment: i have made the changes and removed that part in order to avoid confusion.